# Get JSON from another (php) file using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript. I have a php file that lists all the files in a directory. I want to call that file and get the json array that it echos using only javascript. I know jquery can do it... but this is the only thing I need to do. Its not worth learning jquery for it nor do I want to bloat my page with a library I'm only going to use for this one thing.

Comment: have a look at AJAX - btw, you get use google apis for all sorts of javascript libraries: many sites use them so jquery lib is likely to be already cached by the browser so no extra load - i would really recommend using one of the frameworks out there

Comment: I'd argue it's still worth using jQuery. It's not just shorter code you get, but more stable code as well. If you host the jquery.min.js file on your own server or a CDN, the time it takes to load it is negligible.

Comment: dealing with "pure" ajax is not a simple thing for a begginer - while working with prepared libraries such as jQuery is extremely easy - therefore, you better spend 2 minutes in order to get into it with jquery instead of trying to work directly with AJAX (which is not fully cross platform - a problem that working with jQuery or other libraries solves)

Answer (score 2):

I would say just use jquery as handling all different browsers for AJAX is a pain and I am sure you will use it in the long run for other things too.

If you really want to do this here is an example of a native js request:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
    //suppress error
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}
```

you would use it like this:

```
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   var jsondata=eval("("+mygetrequest.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
   var rssentries=jsondata.items
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}

mygetrequest.open("GET", "mypage.php", true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
```